# Desktop menu hides when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a site http://www.kaniamea.com/resource/
For obvious SEO reasons I am using one html code for both navigation - mobile and desktop. The problem is when you see the site in desktop and you click on one of the left hand navigation links. Then the category the clicked link belongs hides (after the click is clicked).

I am not sure what causes this. I would appreciate some tips how to fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code that toggles the inside unordered list (ul) for the parent li item clicked:

```
$('.main-nav li').click(function (){
    $(this).addClass('im-curent');
    $("ul", this).toggle(100);
});
```

Since all the links are inside the main li, it will close the menu. To fix this, you can stop propagation for the inner ones like:

```
$('.main-nav ul').click(function (e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful! Is there a way to not hide the category links for desktop too?

Comment: If you don't want it to hide at all, just remove the first part of code I mentioned. If you want to hide it when clicking category heading, but not when clicking the links, then use the second part of code I posted.

Comment: I did that but then the categories don't expand for mobile.